# Reactjs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Im new to React.js and I fetch data from API and save them with [Store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) in my LocalStorage

I set the keys and values successfully in the localstorage like this:

```
const takeUsername = cookies => {
    let fullName = JSON.parse(cookies).fullName;

    store.set('user', { fullName: fullName });
};
```

Then i get the fullname in this way:

```
<AccountFound fullName={JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store.get('user').fullName))} />
```

When the localStorage is empty i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined`

Because I get the fullName too early maybe.

So my question is how can I wait for the fullName to be set on LocalStorage so i don't get this error ?

Thank you!

I call takeUsername in this function

```
const setCookies = cookies => {
    let cookie;
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const inputField = document.querySelectorAll(
            'div[data-alpaca-field-path*="/sessionCookie"]:not([style*="display: none"]) input'
        )[i];
        cookie = cookies[i].value;
    }
    checkCookieInApi(cookie).then(res => takeUsername(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    //  disableButton(cookies.length);
};
```

Where i get the cookies and I use them to fetch the API (checkCookieInAPI is the function)

Comment: in which function are you calling takeUsername(cookies) ?? componentDidMount or any other function??

Comment: I made an edit for that

Comment: i can upload the code in github if you want to check it all

Comment: if possible make it on stackblitz??

Comment: yeah but you will not be able to run it after, i build this code for chrome extension

Comment: https://itnext.io/add-state-and-lifecycle-methods-to-function-components-with-react-hooks-8e2bdc44d43d may be this will help you

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, if there is no data in the localStorage it returns an error.

what happens in `store.get('user').fullName` is first it loads localStorage data and then trying to access fullName property on the object that doesn't exist.

consider this:

```
const getUsername = () => {
  const userData = store.get('user')
  const userFullName = userData && userData.fullName 
    ? userData.fullName
    : 'Store is empty';

  return userFullName;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I would like to wait for the fullName not to display the error 'Store is empty'

Comment: when you save something to storage and then try to load it - does it load correctly?

Comment: ```store.set('user', { fullName: 'fullName test' }); console.log(store.get('user'));``` - if this outputs `{ fullName: 'fullName test' }`, it means saving and reading works well. store seems to be synchronous, JS will wait for it's completion before executing new line of code

Comment: yes it loads but the saving process takes longer than the reading so it give me the error fullName not found. (this happends only the first try when the localStorage is empty) i want to delay the process of reading or to repeat it if the storage is empty.

Comment: from what you are saying: **this happens only the first try when the localStorage is empty** - this is exactly why it says "user" is undefined. If there is nothing in the localStorage(aka storage is empty), how would it return fullName? If the code from my comment above works - you need to handle specific case when there is no data in localStorage yet. Perhaps open modal where user is asked to enter name or maybe set it to John Doe :)